# external usb hard drive is not being seen anymore

Tags: 11.04, usb, external-hdd

I think my problem is a little different than several other similar titled questions.

Everything started while I was using 10.10. External drive was always recognized and mounted, but the timing of this differed. I mean when I booted, the OS sometimes saw the drive immediately, sometimes after a few minutes, sometimes after hours. Although this was annoying, I tolerated this somehow.

Then this problem persisted after I upgraded to 11.04 with a clean install. Afterwards, the drive became totally invisible to the OS. It is not even detected as an usb device anymore.

However, there is one thing I can do to make it seen. If I boot to another operating system which can detect the drive, and then boot back to ubuntu, everything is perfect. but this is of course very impractical.

To summarize, the usb drive is recognized by ubuntu if and only if another OS in the same computer could recognize it first. I should also say I have not had any problems with the same drive in any other OS or a different computer.

My drive is philips with a hitachi hdd inside, has its own power source and any other usb powered drives have never caused this kind of a problem.

I've tried almost all recommendations in similar topics but none of them seems to be related to this one. What can I possibly do to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to hotplug it?

Comment: yep. did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the state of the USB hardware isn't being properly initialized (in the USB logic in the enclosure). I suspect once you've fully booted Ubuntu, if you power cycle your enclosure, give it a few seconds, then plug it in over USB, that you'll be able to use it normally. If not, please post the last 30 lines or so of "dmesg" from about 10 seconds after plugging the drive in.

I suppose it's remotely possible this could be a missing kernel module too, but I really doubt that.

Comment: dmesg log gives, and repeats:  "[ 621.492483] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2". I changed the port to see if this is the hard disk and apparently it is.

Comment: So, you changed USB ports and everything's fine? Or have you managed to verify your drive has a hardware problem?

Comment: no it's not ok. i've concluded that it's the drive. all other drives work fine. i'm going to give it to my windows using brother and maybe get myself a new small drive.